# Invisible edges when applying pixel shader to model

Tags: graphics, directx, shader, hlsl, pixel-shader

I am currently working on a simple shader in hlsl. What I am trying to achieve is 'highlight' effect when cursor is placed on the object in my screen. My issue is that, the pixel shader doesn't work correctly:

[image]

In the picture number 1 there is an object without any effect applied. Picture number 2 shows the object with effect.

As you can see edges are no longer visible. How to improve my pixel shader? Pixel shader code:

```
sampler cubeSampler : register (s0);

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 Position : POSITION;
  float2 UV : TEXCOORD;
};

float4 main(VertexShaderOutput vertex) : COLOR
{
        float4 color = tex2D(cubeSampler, vertex.UV.xy);
        float value = 0.3f * color.r + 0.59f * color.g + 0.11f * color.b;       //Desaturated hue
        float3 tint = float3(0.26f, 0.37f, 0.67f);                              //Filter color (R: 68, G: 95, B: 173)
        float tintMix = 0.8f;

        float OutputR = tintMix * value * tint.r + (1 - tintMix) * color.r;
        float OutputG = tintMix * value * tint.g + (1 - tintMix) * color.g;
        float OutputB = tintMix * value * tint.b + (1 - tintMix) * color.b;

        return float4(OutputR, OutputG, OutputB, 255);
}
```

Comment: Also, remember that color values work on the [0;1] range. You're returning an alpha of 255 there

Comment: @EmilioMartinez yup, my mistake. But i think it doesn't change anything except it looks bad - if value is bigger than 1 it is set to 1 by default ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set the same color along the entire surface, without consider normals influence. You have to take a look at lambert and phong shading model if you want to replicate picture in the left. It's a little bit more complicated.

Here you can find a nice explanation:

https://takinginitiative.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/directx-10-tutorial-8-lighting-theory-and-hlsl/